# Which Cthulhu Confidential scenarios can be played as one-shots, without spoiling the campaigns?

Tags: published-adventures, gumshoe, gumshoe-one-2-one, cthulhu-confidential

With the exception of *The Red Mist*, all published Cthulhu Confidential scenarios use one of the three protagonists from the original campaigns. Does that mean that these scenarios work best when inserted into those campaigns? After playing and loving *The Red Mist*, we'd like to play another one, without the commitment of a full campaign -- but also leaving the door open, i.e. without the one-shot spoiling anything from any of the three campaigns.

Maybe if one of them is a prequel to its respective campaign, that would work as a one-shot? It is hard to tell without reading them, but if I read them and they do contain spoilers, then it'd be too late already...

Comment: I recommend making the actual question more clear. The question as posed in the title (imho not the place to put a question that isn't repeated in the body of the question btw) is probably off topic, since it's a recommendation question. *"Do scenarios like these work as oneshots?"* or *"What kind of scenarios do I need (to avoid) for oneshots?"* would probably be on topic.

Comment: @fabian: does it look better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I misunderstood the nature of the core Cthulhu Confidential rulebook. It contains only one scenario for each protagonist, instead of one *campaign* per protagonist, like I thought. So there is no campaign to commit to in the first place.

On the other hand, having played the Dex Raymond scenario *High Voltage Kill*,

> it is possible for the protagonist to become a mindless mi-go puppet by the end of the scenario, which can cause continuity issues with other Dex Raymond scenarios.